# Access attributes in model in after_validation block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm attempting to modify attributes from of the model, in the after_validation callback of a model, however all the @attributes are returning nil so the method fails.

How can I access the @attributes of the ActiveRecord before save, but after validation. 
I'm attempting to access it from a method within the class itself.

```
    class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
            attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude
            geocoded_by :address
            after_validation :geocode

            # Returns a human readable address from our various fields
            def address
                # All of these are nil when this gets called, from the geocode block which gets called by after_validation
                [self.street + self.street2, self.city, self.state].compact.join(', ')
            end
    end
```

Comment: Not much of it too post, but sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing in an instance variable should work:

```
after_validation {|x| @this = x; geocode}

def address
  [@this.street + @this.street2, @this.city, @this.state].compact.join(', ')
end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on this answer (semantics, thinking behind this approach, why my approach does not work) ?

Comment: I am not sure why your approach does not work. I tested a basic after_validation implementation and called logger.debug(self.content)  in a method and it worked as you expected.  My only guess is that geocode is doing something that prevents the attributes from being visible but without seeing that method I don't know for sure.  That being said, creating an instance variable that holds the content regardless of what geocode is doing and accessing it instead of the content on the object directly should fix the problem.